# How to write and query data from elasticsearch within several concurrent processes?

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I am writing a simple application in Scala that listens to Kafka on different topics and when an event on writing comes I write the data down in ElasticSearch. I'm using *elastic4s* as a wrapper around ElasticSearch Java API. So listening to different topics is implemented as concurrent processes that are run in Futures. This code in my app looks like

```
Future { container.orangesHandler.runMessagesHandling() }
Future { container.lemonsHandler.runMessagesHandling() }
Future { container.limesHandler.runMessagesHandling() }
Future { container.mandarinsHandler.runMessagesHandling() }
```

For writing to ElasticSearch I have a helper object that contains an *ElasticClient* `private val client = ElasticClient.transport(uri)` which connects to ElasticSearch and by means of which I write data. To implement writing I have the following methods in this object:

```
def update(indexName: String, objectType: String, data: String) =
        checkForIndexAndTypeExistence(indexName, objectType).flatMap { response =>
            client.execute {
                index into indexName -> objectType source data
            }
        }

private def checkForIndexAndTypeExistence(indexName: String, objectType: String) =
    client.execute(indexExists(indexName)).flatMap { response =>
        if (!response.isExists)
            client.execute(create index indexName mappings (mapping(objectType) templates(dynamicTemplate)))
        else
            checkForTypeExistence(indexName, objectType)
    }

private def checkForTypeExistence(indexName: String, objectType: String) =
    client.execute(typesExist(objectType) in indexName).flatMap { response =>
        if (!response.isExists())
            client.execute(putMapping(indexName / objectType) templates(dynamicTemplate))
        else Future(true)
    }
```

The problem is when I run 3 Futures all works fine. But when I add the fourth Future it doesn't work. Specifically client doesn't work, it just responds with *Promise* that never completes. One interesting detail: when I run this app on a computer with a quad-core processor it works fine with four Futures.

Comment: Are your handling methods long running just waiting on kafka? If so you're going to be stealing threads from the general purpose ExecutionContext to block. You're better off putting them into a dedicated thread pool ExecutionService (or wrapping that as another ExecutionContext if you really want to).

Comment: Can you explain it in more details, please? :)

Comment: As far as I understand, I run listening to kafka in Future and within this Future another computation is started when an event arrives. And eventually when I run many Futures it leads to a deadlock because a default ExecutionContext has as many threads as your computer has CPUs. So I need a inner Future to supply with it's own ExecutionService. Am I right?